# IE11 Server 2012r2: Trusted Sites treated as Internet Sites in Enhanced Protected Mode Context?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2012, protected-mode

I am trying to automate some tasks on Internet Explorer using AutoIT. I am using AutoIT's IE.au3 library.

I have Enhanced Protected Mode enabled for my machine.
I want to disable it (and Protected Mode) for a specific site and I am using IE 11. According to MS documentation - Enhanced Protected Mode must have Protected Mode enabled in order to work. I tested this by disabling protected mode for all zones, and indeed confirmed it - Enhanced Protected Mode was not launched. So I figured - if I'll add the site to "Trusted Sites" zone where the Protected Mode is disabled, Enhanced Protected Mode should not launch.

The result:

I get the following behavior: IE still opens in "Sandboxed IE" (meaning, a process with Integrity Level "AppContainer" - Enhanced Protected Mode is still enabled!).

Then, if I turn off Protected Mode for Internet Zone - then the Enhanced Protected Mode is really disabled for the site, and I get an IE that is not Sandboxed.

So my conclusion - IE treats the trusted site as internet site (at least as far as Enhanced Protected Mode is concerned). I also found evidence for this (probably, bug) in the following site: http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2011/09/22/internet-explorer-s-explicit-security-zone-mappings.aspx

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I also thought that maybe my addition to trusted sites zone was faulty - so I checked with URLs with dots(such as http://10.10.3.255/mypage) and URLs without dots (such as http://mysite/mypage ) - according to some Microsoft documentation (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361896.aspx ) -the former translate to Internet Zone and the latter translate to Intranet zone. However I found out that it is about the Internet Zone in both cases. Perhaps my configuration was faulty? I tried adding "10.10.3.255", "http://10.10.3.255", "10.10.3.255/*" but I couldn't see any difference in results

Thanks!

Comment: anyone in the crowd? :)